# Python Regular Expressions for a question mark

Tags: python, regex

Am working on a data set with a column next review date. This column have missen fields represented by a question mark(?)

I want to capture this ? with a regular expression then seperate all rows with no review date from the rest of the data.

Question: What is the expression to distinctly match a question mark? (**?**)

Comment: Have you tried '\?'

Answer (score 3):

Backslash before question mark means "literally match a question mark"

```
\?
```

Also, putting a question mark into a character class will mean it's matched literally rather than having its typical "0 or 1 of the previous" meaning

```
[?]
```

Thus:

```
bcd[?]
bcd\?
```

Will both match data that looks like:

```
abcd?efg
 ^^^^
```

If you want to match data that is just a question mark and nothing else, use the start ^ and end $ markers:

```
^\?$
```

Consider though that it may be faster not to use regex and just do a simple "string contains" check for the presence of a question mark if that's literally all you're doing, and don't require complex pattern matching and value capture

Comment: Thanks Caius. Nothing seems to work. Really strange! Does it have to do with the column being a date? Want to match just ? and nothing else

Comment: What does "the column being a date" mean? Show a screenshot of the app in which you see the "column" (upload the screenshot to e.g. imgur and paste the link) - i want to see example data as well as the program that is showing it